# tumblr get list users by hashtag

Tags: tumblr

I can't find the way to look for users on tumblr with a specific hashtag.
Example with hashtag "garden". How can you get a **list with all users** who used this hashtag? And if possible within a certain timeframe?

I guess it's easy but I can't find it.

kind regards

Comment: Sadly that kinda of request isn't supported but the Tumblr API: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it discusses a feature that isn't support by the Tumblr API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just fetch all users who have used a tag, but you can iterate through posts that have that tag. Use the [`/v2/tagged`](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method) route in the Tumblr API.

```
GET /v2/tagged?tag=garden
```

Parse the response as json and fetch each `response[i].blog_name` to construct a list of blog names that have used the tag.

You can then fetch the next page by using the `response[i].timestamp` field of the last post in the array. Just pass it as a `before` query parameter in your next request.

```
GET /v2/tagged?tag=garden&before=1480712397
```

If you'd like to limit to a specific timeframe, you can just start with the most recent date in `before`, and proceed until you hit a post with a `timestamp` past your oldest date.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. First have to check out how to work with the API, but looks a great solution!